# Writing Functions that Return a Value in C++

Tags: c++, return-value

I have this assignment for my intro to programming class and I am having trouble as the terminal keeps on displaying this error:

Calculator.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:

Calculator.cpp:30:10: warning: ‘result’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]

result = sum(numberOne, numberTwo,result);

This is my current code in C++

```
// Calculator.cpp - This program performs arithmetic, ( +. -, *. / ) on two numbers.
// Input:  Interactive
// Output:  Result of arithmetic operation

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// Write performOperation() function declaration here
double sum(double numberOne, double numberTwo, double result);
double difference(double numberOne, double numberTwo, double result);
double product(double numberOne, double numberTwo, double result);
double quotient(double numberOne, double numberTwo, double result);

int main()
{
   double numberOne, numberTwo;
   string operation;
   double result;

   cout << "Enter the first number: ";
   cin >> numberOne;
   cout << "Enter the second number: ";
   cin >> numberTwo;
   cout << "Enter an operator (+.-.*,/): ";
   cin >> operation;

   // Call performOperation method here
   if (operation == "+")
       result = sum(numberOne, numberTwo, result);
   else if (operation == "-")
       result = difference(numberOne, numberTwo, result);
   else if (operation == "*")
       result = product(numberOne, numberTwo, result);
   else if (operation == "/")
       result = quotient(numberOne, numberTwo, result);
   else
       cout << "Please enter a valid operator." << endl;

   if (operation == "+" || operation == "-" || operation == "*" || operation == "/")

   {
       cout << numberOne;
       cout << " " << operation << " ";
       cout << numberTwo;
       cout << " = ";
       cout << result << endl;
   }

   return 0;

} // End of main() function

// Write perform Operation function here

double sum(double numberOne, double numberTwo, double result)
{
   result = numberOne + numberTwo;
   return result;
}

double difference(double numberOne, double numberTwo, double result)
{
   result = numberOne - numberTwo;
   return result;
}

double product(double numberOne, double numberTwo, double result)
{
   result = numberOne * numberTwo;
   return result;
}

double quotient(double numberOne, double numberTwo, double result)
{
   result = numberOne / numberTwo;
   return result;
}
```

I tried initializing the result in 0.0 but the error ensues. We use this Cengage Learning thing and it only displays 80% complete.

```
double result=0.0;
```

Comment: Your "result" should be *EITHER* an input parameter, *OR* a return value ... but not BOTH.  SUGGESTION: 1) Eliminate "double result" from your argument list, 2) declare `double result = ...` as the first line of your functions.

Answer (score 3):

The problem stems from your third argument on each of your functions:

```
double sum(double numberOne, double numberTwo, double result);
                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You don't need to pass the `result` *in* to your function, because you'll be returning the result in the `return` statement. Remove the third argument, adjust all your calls to the functions, and you will avoid this warning.

The reason you're getting this warning is the compiler sees the call to `sum()` or whatever, sees that you're passing in the value of `result`, but `result` is uninitialized. Since you don't need to pass it at all, removing that parameter solves this problem.